# Get size of dimensions in array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

How to get the dimensions given a multidimensional array?
Edit: it could be of 1, 2, or 3 dimensions but each sub-array has the same length.

i.e. for

```
var a = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1]]
```

would be [2,3]

Comment: what is sub lists are different sizes?

Comment: So far, this is the best answer I've found: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13814933/975097

Comment: Ever since `.reduce()` got added to the Array prototype, this has been a one-liner both for fixed inner length (`const dimensions = [a.length, a[0].length]`) as well as uneven length (`const dimensions = [a.length, a.reduce((t,e) => Math.max(t, e.length), 0)]`). The latter yielding the same answer as the first for stably sized input.

Answer (score 39):

```
const dimensions = [ arr.length, arr[0].length ];
```

This works, if you know `length` of the inner arrays never change.

---

If the dimension of the inner arrays aren't static ([jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)), you could combine [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to calculate the largest dimension:

```
const dimensions = [
    arr.length,
    arr.reduce((x, y) => Math.max(x, y.length), 0)
];
```

Comment: `"["+arr.length+","+arr[0].length+"]"` :)

Comment: function arraySize(arr){return {c: arr.length, r:arr[0].length === undefined?1:arr[0].length };}

Comment: or, for uneven inner dimensions: `dimensions = [ a.length, a.reduce((t,e) => Math.max(t, e.length), 0) ];`

Comment: For the former, I'm afraid you forgot the possibility of arr.length == 0, thus causing ArrayIndexOutOfBound or something

Answer (score 10):

Considering that sub lists can have different size, get the minimum size or depending on need make it max

```
function size(ar){
    var row_count = ar.length;
    var row_sizes = []
    for(var i=0;i<row_count;i++){
        row_sizes.push(ar[i].length)
    }
    return [row_count, Math.min.apply(null, row_sizes)]
}
size([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
```

Output:

```
[2, 3]
```

Comment: Would this work for arrays of any dimension, or just for two-dimensional arrays?

Comment: @AndersonGreen it is only for two dimensional, but a recursive call should make it work for N dimesnions

Answer (score 6):

Getting the number of elements of multi-dimensional arrays is as simple as this...

```
var Size = a.join(',').split(',').length;
```

Comment: Hi. Try to elaborate as to why your solution work.

Comment: That seems to be the shortest way doing it, thanks

Comment: @NisanthReddy: the join() concats all elements regardless of array dimension separated by "," chars, then the split separates them at the "," chars deleting them, leaving just a 1D array of all the elements, whose length is reported. However the this will fail if any element(s) contain one or more "," chars in their value. This is true of any separating char used, so the best bet is to use a random string joiner/splitter like Math.random().toString(36)+Math.random().toString(36) .

Answer (score 5):

This works for whatever dimension (supposing that each sub array has the same length):

```
function getDim(a) {
    var dim = [];
    for (;;) {
        dim.push(a.length);

        if (Array.isArray(a[0])) {
            a = a[0];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return dim;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var dim = [
    a.length,
    a[0].length
];
```

This should work, given that each sub array is the same length, however, if thats not the case, you might want to do something like:

```
function findDim(a){
    var mainLen = 0;
    var subLen = 0;

    mainLen = a.length;

    for(var i=0; i < mainLen; i++){
        var len = a[i].length;
        subLen = (len > subLen ? len : subLen);
    }

    return [mainLen, subLen];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

this function will check if the array is valid (not a scalar nor a string) and if the elements of that array are valid (they have the same length) then give the dimensions if all conditions are satisfied or throw an error if else.

```
function getDim(x){
    dim=[]
    try {
        // throw error if the passed variable is a string or a scalar
        if((isFinite(x) && !x.length) || typeof(x)=='string') throw  'This is a scalar or a string  not an array!';
        // loop over the array to extract length of each element.
        // if we get an element that is not an array, return the found dimensions 
        while (x){

            dim.push(x.length)
            currentLevel=x
            x=Array.isArray(x[0])?x[0]:false;
            // check if all elements of the array are of equal dimention. If not, throw an error
            ans=currentLevel.every((value,index,arr)=>{ return value.length==x.length}) ;
            if(!ans) throw 'elements of the array are not of equal dimension !'

        }
        return dim
    } catch (error) {
        return error 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do a recursive function to calculate the shape of an array assuming all the dimensions are identical:

```
arrayShapeRecursive = arr => {
  return arr.length ? [...[arr.length], ...arrayShapeRecursive(arr[0])] : [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can simply use `arr.length` and `arr[0].length` to find the width and the depth.

Often, the arrays will have variable depths which makes it necessary to iterate through the entire array using recursion.

I created a `prototype method` of `Object` to get determine how deep the array is. To use it simply call `myArray.dimensionsDeep()`. It works for both `Objects` and `Arrays`.

```
Object.prototype.isMultidimensional = function()
{
    return this.constructor.name !== "String" && Object.keys(this).some((i) => { return this[i].length > 0; });
}

Object.prototype.dimensionsDeep = function()
{
    if (typeof Object.dimensions === 'undefined')
    {
        if (!this.length)
            return 0;
        Object.dimensions = 0;
        Object.currentLevel = 0;
    }
    Object.keys(this).forEach((i) =>
    {
        if (this[i].isMultidimensional())
        {
            Object.currentLevel++;
            if (Object.currentLevel > Object.dimensions)
                Object.dimensions = Object.currentLevel;
            this[i].dimensionsDeep();
        }
    });
    Object.currentLevel--;
    if (Object.currentLevel < 0)
    {
        delete(Object.currentLevel);
        var temp = Object.dimensions;
        delete(Object.dimensions);
        return temp + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1]];
var size=[];
while(s=a.pop) size.push(s.length);
```

Or if you want to have the length inside `a`:

```
var a = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1]];
for(i in a) a[i]=a[i].length;
```

Edit: 
    I apologize, I wasn't in the subject. The following code calculate max row and column for a two dimensional array.

```
var innerSize = 0, i=0, l=a.length, l2;
for(;i<l;i++) if(innerSize<(l2=a[i].length)) innerSize = l2
[l, innerSize]
```

You can change the `<` to `>` if you want the minimum size.

Answer (score 0):

```
//// From https://gist.github.com/srikumarks/4303229 ////
// Assumes a valid matrix and returns its dimension array.
// Won't work for irregular matrices, but is cheap.
function dim(mat) {
    if (mat instanceof Array) {
        return [mat.length].concat(dim(mat[0]));
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}
```

All credit to https://gist.github.com/srikumarks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go; the code below **works for any dimensional matrix/array**.

```js
function getMatrixDimensions(matrix, dimensions = []) {
  if (Array.isArray(matrix)) {
    dimensions.push(matrix.length);
    return getMatrixDimensions(matrix[0], dimensions);
  } else return dimensions;
}

// Example
console.log(getMatrixDimensions([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
]));
```