# getting dimension of a 2d array in node js

Tags: arrays, node.js

I'm working on a discord bot in node js and i need to get the length of the 2 dimentions of a 2d array.
My array is structurated like this, that algo get expanded at the bottom when needed:

```js
var users = [["","","","",""]];
```

now i need to know how to get the dimentions.
i was originaly doing like this, but it didn't work .

```js
// for the y length
users.length

// for the x length
users[i].length
```

hope you can help

thanks in advance

Enrico

Comment: What about your approach did not work? The code you're showing seems fine, it should work. Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237615/get-size-of-dimensions-in-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you almost are correct:

```
var users = [[1,2],[3,4]]
users.length // y
users[0].length // x
```

Just keeps in mind that index for each X demantion statred since zero , and might be different  for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that none of the elements in the array varies its length from the first one you could just get the length of the first element with

```
var dimensions = [users.length, users[0].length]
// returns [1, 5]
```

In a more practical world, probably is better for you to get the dimensions on each of the elements on the array users and decide on whether to use the biggest or the smallest, naturally I'll chose the biggest.

```
var users = [["", "", ""], ["", ""], ["", "", "", ""]];
var elementsLength = users.map((user) => (user.length));
var lengthY = Math.max(...elementsLength);
var lengthX = users.length;
var dimensions = [lengthX, lengthY];
// returns [3, 4]
```

It all depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your array `var users = [["","","","",""]];` is a 2d array where only the 0th index is occupied.  In your case, `users[i].length` would probably throw a `length not defined` error of some sort at index 1 and beyond.  You should used `users[0].length` to get the length of the 2d element